# How to place the information from a void pointer into a char array?

Tags: c, pointers, void

I am trying to put the information from a void pointer into a char array to keep track of what is at the beginning of a file instead of having to read the file every time I want to write to it to make sure something illegal is not being written.

Example:

```
unsigned long write_file_at(File file, void *data, unsigned long num_bytes,
                            SeekAnchor start, long offset) {
  fserror=NONE;
  if (! file->fp || ! seek_file(file, start, offset)) {
    fserror=WRITE_FAILED;
  }
  else if (offset == 0L && !strncmp(data, "MZ", 2) && start == BEGINNING_OF_FILE){
    fserror = ILLEGAL_MZ;
```

This works fine as intended.
Then if the write is legal and it writes to the first byte of the file I want to place they byte it writes in a char array to keep track across writes

examples in the same write function later on:
(somewhat ignore the long if statement, still a wip)

```
 else{
    bytes_written=fwrite(data, 1, num_bytes, file->fp);
    if ((num_bytes == 1 || num_bytes == 2) && (start == BEGINNING_OF_FILE
                                               || (start == END_OF_FILE && offset == -(ftell\
(file->fp)))
                                               || (start == CURRENT_POSITION && offset == -(\
ftell(file->fp))))){
      file->mem[0] = (char *)data;} //This is what I am struggling with


    if (bytes_written < num_bytes) {
      fserror=WRITE_FAILED;
    }
  }
  return bytes_written;
}
```

How do I pull the fisrt letter/byte written from the data pointer and place it in a char array?

Comment: "to keep track of what is at the beginning of a file" - How is apointer in any way helpful for this? You are aware the value of a pointer is only valid for the lifetime of the object it points to, are you? In other words: End your process and the value in the file is pointless - literally.

Comment: And what is `File`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `->mem` is the char array, you need to dereference the char-cast pointer:

```
file->mem[0] = * /*<= DEREF*/ (char *)data;
```